# Sort users by meta key value even if meta key not present for all users

Tags: user-meta, order, sort

Only some users have a specifice meta_key `some_metakey` associated with their ID.
The following args successfully orders users with a specified role by `some_metakey` but only those with that meta_key.

Can anyone point the direction to change the args to include ALL users with a specified role even if they do not have the `some_metakey` meta_key?

```
$args = array(
    'role__in' => 
    [ 
        'role1', 
        'role2', 
        'role3', 
        'role4' 
    ],
    'order' => 'DEC', 
    'meta_key' => 'some_metakey',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress roles are stored in `$wpdb->usermeta` with `wp_capabilities` meta key, however, as a `serialized` array (see [`maybe_serialize`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/)).

So you could actually make a group of meta queries, with `OR` as the relation, to find users with any role of your 4 defined roles, OR users having a certain meta key and value:

Please note that in you change the roles, make sure to calculate the character length for that role, and place that length after `s:` characters (e.g; for `administrator`, the meta value search will be `s:13:"administrator";b:1`, and `s:10:"subscriber";b:1` for `subscriber` users).

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => [ 
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => 'wp_capabilities',
            'value' => 's:5:"role1";b:1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'wp_capabilities',
            'value' => 's:5:"role2";b:1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'wp_capabilities',
            'value' => 's:5:"role3";b:1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'wp_capabilities',
            'value' => 's:5:"role4";b:1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'some_metakey',
            'value' => 'YOUR VALUE HERE',
            'compare' => '=', // or any other comparator, see WP_Meta_Query docs
        ],
    ],
    // 'order' => 'DESC', 
    // 'meta_key' => 'some_metakey',
    // 'orderby' => 'meta_value'
);

$users = get_users( $args );
```

Now for the ordering, that can get difficult - if you do not limit your queries then you could just do a [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) order on the result array, otherwise, look into [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/), they have some hooks to use to manipulate the class state and hence the SQL query.

Comment: I amended the final section, `[ 'meta_key' => 'some_metakey', 'value' => 0, 'compare' => '>', ],`. It returns all users, even those not in any specified roles, alphabetically by username.  (The `some_metakey` meta_key is the last login date). Without the final section, the correct users are returned but obviously unsorted. I don't believe usort will work as meta data is not included in the user objects returned. I've seen the use of a loop to get each user's `some_metakey` value and then perform a sort. I may end up going this route but I have a feeling it can be achieved more simply.

Comment: If all else fails just query the database with `$wpdb` global. You're using `OR` in the `meta_query` relation, so if any rule is met, a user will be selected, so your users probably all have a login date that's `> 0`